# Open Android Location Settings using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I'm using user's geolocation via phonegap.The exapmle is shown below. (ANDROID)

```
  // onSuccess Callback
    // This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
    // current GPS coordinates
    //
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '+ position.coords.latitude         +'<br/>' +
               'Longitude: '            + position.coords.longitude        +<br/>' +
               'Altitude: '             + position.coords.altitude         +'<br/>' +
               'Accuracy: '             + position.coords.accuracy         +<br/>' +
               'Altitude Accuracy: '    + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy +'<br/>' +
               'Heading: '              + position.coords.heading          +<br/>' +
                'timestamp: '            + position.timestamp              +<br/>';
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

Is it possible (using phonegap) on error function to open dialog which will lead us to location settings (where user will be able to give me access to his location) instead of alert, as it's done in google maps android application (screenshot below) ?
[image: like this]

Comment: did u add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest file

Comment: yes of course, I have access to user's location, my problem is open settings page on error

Comment: Use a plugin like: https://github.com/romainperruchon/gpssettings/blob/master/src/android/com/dataforpeople/plugins/GpsSettings.java.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do just what you are saying, create the dialog, and send them to settings; I'm assuming you have managed to get the onError fcn called at the apropos time, so then

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.loc_man));
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.ask_for_gps));
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);       
            }
        });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.gps_no), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    builder.create().show();
```

what you also need to do is call this function from your javascript... Oh, this is fun, b/c you'll be using a lot of pretty cool java concepts all at once and I've only worked with Cordova, but this should all work the same =] Keep in mind that if you see some variable undefined in my code, you should probably assume it's a feild.

so let's say you are sure this code hits on error, let's make up an interface name; 'Android' is a pretty logical one

```
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    Android.TurnOnTuneIn();
}
```

now back in your Java, grep around your phonegap app to find wherever it has 'WebView'; if it's anything like my cordova implementations, it'll have webview.loadUrl() in it somewhere. Open the file that defines this class; this is the one to edit/place all the java we are working on in this question. After something like 'public class PhoneGapActivity extends Activity', insert 'implements CordovaInterface' ( I think not PhoneGapInterface ); if your IDE gives you an error with the option to implement abstract methods, pound that.

Make sure the WebView is a feild in the class, not a variable in a method, then

```
    //CordovaWebView should work, but maybe it needs to be PhoneGapWebView, you're smart, you'll figure it out =]
            webView = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.data_window);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED); //this always seemed like a good idea to me
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "Android"); //see the interface name? =]
//this line should already be in this class, just re-use it
webView.loadUrl("file:///"+getContext().getFilesDir().toString()+"/index.html");
```

now make that interface:

```
public class JSInterface {
    // these fcns are exposed to the WebView 
    private Context context;
    public JSInterface(Context context)
    {
        context = context;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void doEchoTest(String echo)
    {
//A useful test; I usually use it in a webViewClient that runs the function that calls this in my javascript with this:
//webView.loadUrl("javascript:echo('"echo!!!"');"); //this exact formatting
//but webViewClient is outside the scope of your question and would just confuse the 
//issue; however, you may need to implement 
//webViewClient with an delaying asynctask to seperatly run the js you loaded with the webpage,
//again, I used to do this ground-up, and phoneGap Might Just Work.

        Toast.makeText(context, echo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void TurnOnTuneIn
    {
        aMethodThatHasThatFirstBitOfCodeIPublished();
    }
}
```

I love interfaces =]

The rest is fairly boilerplate for your purposes ( but fun to play with nevertheless! ) and you might not need much if any of it. If you notice the method I put up top is not returning the way you want it to, you can use the startActivityForResult method to do the same and I'll bet it'll work nicely; Note the 'super.' call that the Override makes; you only need the Intent ( like I showed you up top ) and some reference number for receiving the result... again, out of the scope of the question. ALso, I included support for the ResultCallback b/c a guy I was working with used it, but I don't use it myself.

```
@Override
public Activity getActivity(){
    return this;
}

@Override
public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
    this.activityResultCallback = plugin;
}

public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command, Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    this.activityResultCallback = command;
    this.activityResultKeepRunning = this.keepRunning;

// If multitasking turned on, then disable it for activities that return results
    if (command != null) {
        this.keepRunning = false;
    }

// Start activity
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}

@Override
public void cancelLoadUrl(){
//  no op
}

@Override
public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
        LOG.d("is", "onMessage(" + id + "," + data + ")");
        if ("exit".equals(id)) {
            super.finish();
        }
        return null;
}
@Override 
public void onPause() {
    Method pause = null; // Pauses the webview. 
    try { 
        pause = WebView.class.getMethod("onPause"); 
    } 
    catch (SecurityException e) { } 
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { } 
    if (pause != null) {
        try { pause.invoke(webView); 
        } 
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) { } 
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) { } 
    } 
    else { 
    // No such method. Stores the current URL. 
        suspendUrl = webView.getUrl(); // And loads a URL without any processing. 
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nothing.html"); 
    } 
    super.onPause(); 
}

@Override 
public void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    Method resume = null; // Resumes the webview. 
    try { 
        resume = WebView.class.getMethod("onResume"); 
    } 
    catch (SecurityException e) { } 
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { } 
    if (resume != null) { 
        try { 
            resume.invoke(webView); 
        } 
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) { } 
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) { } 
    } 
    else if (webView != null) { // No such method. Restores the suspended URL. 
        if (suspendUrl == null) { 
            //this should be wherever you have your page; you can probably copy it from what is there now.
webView.loadUrl("file:///"+getContext().getFilesDir().toString()+"/index.html");
        } 
        else { 
            webView.loadUrl(suspendUrl); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Hope that gets you further along; if you don't use it already, remember to use version control, so you can be reckless with your edits!

gl hf

Comment: I don't know java at all, so this is my first steps on phonegap only and I don't know what to do with the code you give to me, can you explain in details

Answer (score 0):

I share with you, this phonegap plugin, that lets you do that. I added that functionality to that plugin as a contribuitor.
https://github.com/BastienL/GPSDetector